# algorithm to convert from money to other without directly conversor

Tags: algorithm, logic

i need to do a currency conversor.

Suppose you have a list of objects with currency money and his value in other. for Example:

```
From To Value
USD-CAN 0,1
CAN-USD 0,4
USD-AUD 0.5
AUD-USD 0,6
AUD-EUR 1
EUR-AUD 3
```

And you need to convert a list of values from currency money to EUR for example

```
1,22 USD
1,4 CAN
5 AUD
```

There are some values that his convertions its directly (AUD-EUR), but another not(USD-EUR,CAN-EUR).

Witch its the best way or algorithm to do it this..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Construct a directed graph where nodes are currencies and edges are direct conversions. Find shortest path(s) from the source currency to the target currency.

You can set edge weights as *log*(conversion-rate) to find the best conversion path (taking log for adding weights instead of multiplying them).

You may even try to detect [2-point arbitrage](http://www.eagletraders.com/advice/securities/arbitrage.php), [3-point arbitrage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_arbitrage) (look [here](http://shriphani.com/blog/2010/07/02/bellman-ford-algorithms-applications-triangular-arbitrage/) for example) or n-point arbitrage (look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/94414/an-algorithm-for-arbitrage-in-currency-exchange)).

Comment: Nice answer. Thanks for pointing to triangular arbitrage. I was aware of the concept but did not know the technical term for it.